# Placed latitude and longitude coordinates points in North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm new to QGIS and trying to do a map of my plots. To represented my map, I choose to use the Azimuthal Equidistant projection because my plots are distributed between northern Europe and Canada, see here:

[image]

for each plots, I have their latitude and longitude points:

[image]

Thus, I try to upload the points on QGIS to project on my map, but impossible. I think to have understand that it's a problem of coordinates system, but I don't have the cartographic level to well understand.

How can I place my point (lat/long) in Azimuthal projection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geometry CRS field needs to be populated with the CRS of the data being imported, not your project. In this case, EPSG:4326 (WGS84) would work.

QGIS will take care of reprojecting the points on the fly. After they are imported, you could export them to the correct projection.